# How to avoid long space when cross-reference name is empty?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, cleveref

When using [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) one may want to use its macros for making *all* cross-references, even those where the cross-reference name is empty. The cross-reference name is the name that is appended to a cross-reference to describe its type, e.g. a `\cref` to Figure 1 outputs "figure 1" (rather than outputting just "1" like `\ref` does). To define an empty cross-reference name for figures one can, as described in [the manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) on page 19, do as follows:

```
\crefname{figure}{}{}
```

The problem with doing this is that even if the cross-references name indeed is emptied the space before the cross-reference is longer than when just using `\ref`. How can one avoid such a long space?

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\crefname{enumi}{}{}
\crefname{equation}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item foo\label{item:1}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:1}      
\end{equation}

In \cref{item:1}.% Too long space after "In"

In \ref{item:1}.

In \cref{eq:1}.% Too long space after "In"

In \ref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the `cleveref` package but don't want to prefix the "name" of the cross-referenced item (or items), there is no need to undefine the names via various

```
\crefname{xyz}{}{}
```

instructions. Simply use the `\labelcref` command instead of the `\cref` command. As the macro's name suggests, it operates only on the "label" part of the cross-referenced item(s) but otherwise does just the same things as `\cref` does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath,cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo\label{item:1}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2\label{eq:1}      
\end{equation}

In \labelcref{item:1}.

In \ref{item:1}.

In \labelcref{eq:1}.

In \eqref{eq:1}. % \eqref inserts parentheses automatically
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what if you want to use `\cref` for constructs that does not have a cross-reference name, such as linguistic examples that are merely referred to as (1), (2), (3), etc.?

Comment: The `\labelcref` approach works regardless of whether a "name" for an item to be cross referenced has already been defined or not. It's also handy when you want to override an existing "name."

Comment: @N.N: Please be a bit more specific about the "constructs that do not have cross-reference names, such as linguistic examples" that you have in mind. The two examples you gave in your posting (items in an enumerated list, and equations) *do* have default names ("item" and "equation", respectively) set up for them.

Comment: Say, any new list created via `enumitem`.

Comment: @N.N. -- items in such a list have the name "item" by default. At any rate, as my MWE demonstrates, use of `\creflabel` to cross-reference such items is quite problem-free...

Answer (score 5):

In general, using `\labelcref` as per Mico's answer seems to be the correct solution. If you want to use `\cref` for constructs that do not have a cross-reference name, here's a workaround:

```
\crefname{enumi}{\unskip}{\unskip}
\crefname{equation}{\unskip}{\unskip}
```